# Button not firing inside update panel, looked at other questions and none of the fixes work

Tags: c#, asp.net

So, I have this update panel:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" RenderMode="Inline" UpdateMode="Conditional">

    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSubmit" EventName="Click" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddOutcomeType" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddOutcomeCode" />
    </Triggers>

    <ContentTemplate>
        <fieldset>

            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddOutcomeType" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                 OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddOutcomeType_OnSelectedIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Value="0">Please Select...</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="EDU">Continuing in Education</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="EMP">Paid Employment</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="NPE">Not in Paid Employment</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="GAP">Gap Year</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="OTH">Other</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>

            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddOutcomeCode" runat="server" DataTextField="COMPDESC" 
                 DataValueField="EBSVALUE" 
                 OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddOutcomeCode_OnSelectedIndexChanged"
                 AutoPostBack="True" Visible="false" />

            <br /><br />
            <asp:Label ID="lblDestMessage" runat="server" 
                 Text="Please start typing at least 3 characters of the HE institute 
                       then select from the list (Don't make your own up!)" 
                 Visible="false">
            </asp:Label>

            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

            <h4 style="align-content:center;">
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Comments on Destination">
            </asp:Label></h4>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDestComments" runat="server" Width="70%"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="validJust" runat="server" 
                 Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtDestComments" 
                 ValidationExpression="^([\S\s]{0,249})$" CssClass="label label-danger" 
                 ErrorMessage="Please enter maximum 250 characters" 
                 SetFocusOnError="True">
            </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            <br />



            <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
                 CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClick="btnSubmit_OnClick" />

        </fieldset>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I Have looked at other questions for the same problem but none of the fixes work for this, i tried putting the button outside of the update panel but then the Hidden Fields that are changed by the dropdown lists dont stay changed outside of the update panels.

Any Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using UpdateMode property of update panel as UpdateMode="Conditional". Either you have to explicitly use Update() method of update panel in button Click event on server side to update the content inside update panel or remove this UpdateMode property because by default it is set as Always.